# gmaps4rails javascript Can't find variable: OpenLayers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openlayers, asset-pipeline, gmaps4rails

I installed **gmaps4rails** gem for my **rails 3.1.1** application. When I generate a map using google maps everything works fine, but then, when I change my code in the view to:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @locations}, "map_options" =>  { "provider" => "openlayers"}) %>
```

I get the following error in the **javascript console** in Safari :

> ReferenceError: **Can't find variable: OpenLayers**

Here's the part of application.rb that allows asset pipeline to be used:

> ```
> config.assets.enabled = true
> config.assets.version = '1.0'
> ```

I tied running the application both in production mode:

```
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.digest = false
```

And in development mode:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
```

But it's not working. I'm using **Apache + passenger and Bundler**.

The javascript error (Can't find variable: OpenLayers) is being thrown from gmaps4rails.openlayers.js:41 which I can see in the development when the javascripts are not being compressed.

I am including the openlayers.js library in **application.js** as mentioned in the documentation on github:

```
//= require gmaps4rails/openlayers.js
```

Viewing the **source of my generated page** gives me info about the javascripts being included in the head section which are:

```
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.openlayers.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"</script>
<script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/openlayers.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But then later on the page, after the map container tag, where in had `<%= yield :scripts %>`
I apparently get the google maps scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.5/src/markerclusterer_packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsOpenlayers();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.map_options.provider = "openlayers";
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.markers = [];
Gmaps.map.create_markers();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); };

</script>
```

Is there some more configuration necessary one has to do to be able to use OpenLayers Maps then the following:

```
<%= gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @locations}, "map_options" =>  { "provider" => "openlayers"}) %>
```

I hope I didn't miss anything in the documentation which I tried to go through multiple times but didn't find any mention about this..

Comment: Ok, I've solved this by downloading OpenLayers.js and putting it into my lib/assets/javascript folder. Did I miss something in the documentation and it should be done differently or is this "the correct procedure"?

Comment: that was an error in the gem... Thanks and +1

Answer (score 0):

The bug you mentioned is fixed in 1.4.3.